# Error join peer channel when using couchdb hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using a simple basic network with two peers, and creating a channel. It's wotks fine, but when I try to add couch db functionality, returns the error:

```
Channel created, joining Org1...
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.22.0.5:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

This only happen when couch db is enabled, without couchdb, it creates the channel and joins it two peers.

When I start the containers without couchdb I'm using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

And with couchdb

```
 docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
```

The docker-compose-couch.yaml contains:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0


  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "7984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
```

Any idea? Is there any reason to connect error when using couchdb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it adding a little delay when joining the channel.

If a script is creating and joining the channel just after the containers goes up, couchdb container is running but not the database inside it.

My problem was solved adding a "sleep 2" before creating the channel in my script in order to be sure that couchdb database is ready to serve request.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. I looked into the first network example  and it has a function to wait until couchdb is up, copying this function after three retries of 3 seconds it get connected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some problem in connecting with the peer so once down the network, remove all the containers and volumes. Then start with the network setup again.

And try to up docker containers separately this time, i.e. first up all other containers using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

Then, start your couchdb containers as it might be the case that your peer containers are not up while couchdb is up and is trying to search for peer containers. So after all other containers are up then use this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
```